# Забота о мобильных пользователях

Tags: mobile, php

Есть сайт на котором встроен редактор TinyMCE, но я люблю своих посетителей. Всех-всех. А часть из них чего-то вдруг заходит с мобильных телефонов, а эту штука — TinyMCE подгружается в телефонном браузере и не дает заполнять поле.
Как сделать проверку на мобильный браузер и отключить подгрузку редактора?

Подгружается оно вот так:

```
    if($_conf[use_htmleditor]==1){
    $vars[htmleditor]=$_conf[htmleditor]='  <!-- йа редакторъ -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.ru/tinymce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.ru/tinymce/tinyconf.js"></script>
<!-- / йа редакторъ -->';
}
```

Внутри проверка на то, включен ли он в админке. Если "ага", то показывается, если "не-а", то не показывается.
А как вот к этому еще и с мобильными версиями проверку прикрутить?

Answer (score 2):

При `DOMContentLoaded` проверять useragent — чтобы понять, телефон это, или десктопный браузер. Если последнее, то добавлять скрипты динамически:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
link.setAttribute('src', 'http://site.ru/tinymce/tiny_mce.js');
...
```

Comment: а если на PHP делать проверку мобильных браузеров, то такка тогда?

Comment: нужно брать юзерагента из суперглобального массива `$_SERVER`, анализировать (например, с помощью ф-ции http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php, но, возможно, придется самому писать анализатор), выносить вердикт: писать или не писать `echo $vars[htmleditor];`

Comment: Поискать в нете функцию isMobile, которая по юзер-агенту пытается определить. Но сами понимаете не 100%

Answer (score 1):

сделал штуку проще.

```
/*  Проврека мобильного браузера пользователя.
    Если человек с мобильника — то отключить визуальный редактор.   */

    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if(preg_match(тут все реальные мбильные юзерагенты (не смог всё вставить, ограниченное количество символов на хэшкоде. я превысил на 1700 штук.)',substr($useragent,0,4)))
        if($_conf[use_htmleditor]==1){
            $vars[htmleditor]=$_conf[htmleditor]='<!-- для мобильника редакторъ не нужен -->';
        }
    // отключили редактор, вывели коммент в исходние и работаем дальше
```

такая штука сработала и не показывает редактор никому с мобильника. количество постов на сайте выросло на 7%.

спасибо всем, кто помог.

Comment: Готовый класс:  [`http://mobiledetect.net/`](http://mobiledetect.net/)

Comment: ну это сильно крутая штука для моих целей.
спасибо